# Straight line with slowly increasing thickness

Tags: adobe-illustrator

How can I get a straight line that starts thin and gets thicker?

[image]

Of course I can achieve something with the width profiles -> see image above. It must also be possible to change the thickness of the line afterwards. it must be possible for the line to be even thicker at the beginning. I want it to increase in thickness less fast (it should start thicker than the picture above)

I know also the width tool but this doesnt give me the desired result.

What other option exist in Illustrator?
Where can I download appropriate brushes? Which brushes would work for this task?

I tried the arrow brushes:
[image]

But as you can see, this looks very weird as you can always see the arrow shape.... :-S

Many thanks
Kind regards,
Silvan

Comment: its pretty hard to tell you wat to do when you say what doesent work but dont tell us what you want to achive? i mean why dont you draw the brish yourself?

Comment: You can make your own custom Brushes in Illustrator. No need to download any. Draw a any shape you want, and drag it into the brushes panel, choose "Art Brush" as the brush type.  Also there are many brushes included with Illustrator, you will probably have to load them from the Brush libraries [see screenshot](https://imgur.com/JoufSMO).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You *can* use the **Width Tool** to alter the profile of any stroke to match your desired results. It takes some fiddling due to how erratic the Width Tool can be, but it's possible.

[image]

Or you *can* use a **Art Brush**, just change the **Brush Options** to `Stretch to Fit Stroke Length`. You *don't* want to use "Stretch Between Guides" if you want a smooth stretch for the entire shape.

[image]

[image]

Or, for a more pronounced end.... one *would* use `Stretch Between Guides` and adjust artwork accordingly...

[image]

[image]

Comment: you can also double click on point with width tool to type width. also offcourse even without width tool one can change stroke width (its a global multiplier) of a profile too. But for love of god this cant be what op asks?

Comment: Yeah it's kind of difficult to know *exactly* what the desired result are.. but I'm pretty sure whatever they are can be achieved via the Width tool, then saved as a custom provide.

Comment: It seems we agree on that.

Comment: thanks for your help. the advantage of the "stretch between guides" variant is that I can make the line thicker at the end when i move the guides to the left and "stretch between guides" makes adjusting the line later very easy. This is with "fit between stroke length" not possible... is it possible to work with stretch between guides without creating an "arrow" shape? Is there no brush that is designed for this?

Comment: I am really unclear on what you are trying to create and for what usage. It would be *exceptionally* helpful if you edited the question and added some *specific* use and what you see a brush being able to accomplish (even if you "fake" mock it up). Stretch just stretches.. whatever is between the guides.. it doesn't have to be an arrow.